# Flask Posting JSON

Tags: python, curl

I have the following flask route:

```
@app.route('/change_groups', methods = ['POST'])
def change_groups():
  if not request.json:
    return "Not a json post"
  return "json post!"
```

When I curl like this I get back `"Not a json post"` as expected:

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" localhost:8000/change_groups
```

I then try to post json to trigger the `"json post!"` code:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:8000/change_groups
```

The second request also triggers `"Not a json post"` when I was expecting `"json post!"`.

How can I similate posting json to this Flask route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your request you don't set `Content-Type: application/json`, so it won't be parsed as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Found answer quickly, needed to add header data:

```
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```